# Is it possible to workaround storing data in the cloud by publishing to a Power BI workspace?

Tags: database, powerbi, cloud, hardcode

This question is designed to get some information.

I got one table pulled from my SQL server in Power BI. In the same program I also got one hardcoded table (Manual_Input). In my Power BI document, I merge these two tables together by:

```
Table.Combine({Source, Manual_Input})
```

By doing this, the Power BI document is done and I published it to a Power BI workspace.
By publishing the Power BI document, I believe the hardcoded table is saved in the cloud.

Now here is the problem: Let's say I don't want to have the information in hardcoded table to be saved in the cloud. I've thought of the following solution for this:

I will pull the one table from my SQL server. Then, I use the following code to insert the rows with data into this table:

```
= Table.InsertRows(Source, 1, {[ID = "C", Age = 23, Sales = 2000]})
```

Let's say, by adding this row, the Power BI document is done and I publish it to a Power BI workspace, will the inserted rows with data be saved in the cloud as well? Or is this a valid way to workaround storing data in the cloud?

I hope somebody knows.

Comment: Why not have a csv or excel file stored in one drive and connect to it from there, rather than hardcode? You can then update the document as you wish

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported by Power Query.

There is a possibility of using specially created datasets leveraging XMLA-endpoint to "stream" datapoints to a published dataset. Read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-connect-tools

You will need to use other tools than Power Query for this.